# Sudo timeout not working

Tags: sudo

I added this to sudoers, but I am still being prompted for a password.

```
Defaults:USER timestamp_timeout=600
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just double checking... Did you replace `USER` with the actual username?

The steps are:

1. Run `sudo visudo`
2. In the file add at the end `Defaults:USER timestamp_timeout=MINUTES`, where `USER` is the username in question and `MINUTES` is the number of minutes to which you want to set the timeout.
3. Save and close; I would recommend starting a new session before testing that it works.

Comment: Defaults:andy timestamp_timeout=600

Comment: Okay, that's not your problem then. I just tested it myself by setting a 1 minute timeout and it worked. Up to 1 minute I wasn't asked to reenter password and after the minute I was.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the timeout value is limited to 2 digits.

That is only one mistake. This link shows what I missed.

https://itsfoss.com/change-sudo-password-timeout-ubuntu/

I changed it to 90 minutes and it is working.